# while scrolling Text values in Listview are changing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

This is my lauout for the adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/fix_container"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv1"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv2"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv2"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Production_Dispatch_Res_DTO rem_res_dto;
List<String> eff_list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] eff_list_split;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, Production_Dispatch_Res_DTO res, 
List<String> eff_list) {
    this.rem_res_dto = res;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.eff_list = eff_list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eff_list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return eff_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try{
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lists,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        eff_list_split= eff_list.get(position).split(",");

        int eff_list_split_size = eff_list_split.length;

        switch (eff_list_split_size){
            case 1:
                if(eff_list_split[0].equals("-1")){
                    holder.tv1.setText("");
                }
                else
                holder.tv1.setText(eff_list_split[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(eff_list_split[0].equals("-1"))
                    holder.tv1.setText("");
                else
                holder.tv1.setText(eff_list_split[0]);

                if(eff_list_split[1].equals("-1"))
                    holder.tv2.setText("");

                else
                holder.tv2.setText(eff_list_split[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                if(eff_list_split[0].equals("-1"))
                    holder.tv1.setText("");
                else
                    holder.tv1.setText(eff_list_split[0]);

                if(eff_list_split[1].equals("-1"))
                    holder.tv2.setText("");

                else
                    holder.tv2.setText(eff_list_split[1]);

                if(eff_list_split[2].equals("-1"))
                    holder.tv3.setText("");
                else
                holder.tv3.setText(eff_list_split[2]);
                break;
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(VilanConstants.TAG,"/Excp @listAdp"+ e.toString());
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
    public TextView tv3;
}
}
```

I have taken listview in layout like this

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/product_list_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_dispatch"/>
```

At start it is coming correctly. While scrolling listview data in textviews are changing every time I am scrolling.

I have tried the solutions in stackoverflow which are previously answered. But they Won't worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to android.

Thank you.

Comment: try to hard code your data and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Put

```
holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
```

after the

```
if(convertView == null){
     .....
} else {
      ....
}
```

check and try. You are initializing when convertView is null. But do it every time and check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

**Update this code:**

```
 public class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
    public TextView tv3;
  }
```

**to this**

```
public class ViewHolder{
            public TextView tv1;
            public TextView tv2;
            public TextView tv3;

        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code. it is right. but, you need to use all views(TextView) in all cases 1, 2 and 3. because when case 1 is true then only tv1(TextView) is used and others not. so, other views are also used by getView() method automatically. because getView() method called again and again when you scroll list.

**try to use all views in all cases or change logic as you want. but, all views must be used when case is true.**